# Tensorflow object detection API AvgNumGroundtruthBoxesPerImage is always zero (no ground truth labels shown)

Tags: python, tensorflow

As per the title - I can run a training job using the object detection API, but when I look at the loss curve, it's far too smooth. At the eval stage after 1 epoch, the ground truth images are shown in Tensorboard, but no boxes are drawn on them. I have no negative examples in my dataset, so all the images should have labels.

I've tested the Oxford Pet dataset and that works (stats look good and the images show up with boxes in Tensorboard). I've compared my TFRecords to one generated by the Pet script that the model repo provides and there's nothing obvious.

I've converted a set of images and bounding boxes to TFRecords using the following function. It takes in Darknet/Yolo format labels (box centre x/y, box width, box height in normalised units). All the images are 1-channel PNG files (640x512), so I load them and convert them to 3-channel.

I'm not sure if `decode_png` does this automatically if you select three channels, but I didn't want to take the risk so I do the conversion in OpenCV first.

```
def create_tf_example(path, names):
    """Creates a tf.Example proto from sample image

    Returns:
    example: The created tf.Example.
    """

    annotations = load_annotation(path)

    if annotations is None:
        return

    if len(annotations) == 0:
        return

    try:
        with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'rb') as fid:
            image_data = fid.read()

        # Force conversion to 3 channel just to be sure
        image_cv = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(image_data, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        res, image_data = cv2.imencode('.png', image_cv)

        image_data = image_data.tostring()

        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_png(
                image_data,
                channels=3,
                name=None
        )

    except:
        print("Failed: ", path)
        return

    classes_text = []
    classes = []
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []

    height = 512
    width = 640

    for a in annotations:
        class_id, box_cx, box_cy, box_width, box_height = a

        class_id = int(class_id)

        if class_id < len(names):

            xmin = max(0, float(box_cx - 0.5*box_width))
            assert(xmin >= 0 and xmin <= 1)

            xmax = min(1, float(box_cx + 0.5*box_width))
            assert(xmax >= 0 and xmax <= 1)

            ymin = max(0, float(box_cy - 0.5*box_height))
            assert(ymin >= 0 and ymin <= 1)

            ymax = min(1, float(box_cy + 0.5*box_height))
            assert(ymax >= 0 and ymax <= 1)

            xmins.append(xmin)
            xmaxs.append(xmax)
            ymins.append(ymin)
            ymaxs.append(ymax)
            classes.append(class_id+1)
            classes_text.append(names[class_id].encode('utf8'))

    if len(classes) is None:
        print("Class out of range")
        return

    # Possible we've found annotations with invalid class IDs
    if len(xmins) == 0:
        return

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/height': int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': int64_feature(width),
      'image/filename': bytes_feature(os.path.basename(path).encode('utf8')),
      'image/source_id': bytes_feature(os.path.basename(path).encode('utf8')),
      'image/encoded': bytes_feature(image_data),
      'image/format': bytes_feature('png'.encode('utf8')),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin': float_list_feature(xmins),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax': float_list_feature(xmaxs),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin': float_list_feature(ymins),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax': float_list_feature(ymaxs),
      'image/object/class/text': bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
      'image/object/class/label': int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))

    return tf_example
```

A Darknet annotation file is something like (hence the class_id gets a +1):

```
0 0.251252 0.35801225 0.36322 0.25812092
```

Here's an example test:

```
raw_image_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('/home/josh/data/data/test.record-00000-of-00010')

# Create a dictionary describing the features.  
image_feature_description = {
    'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
    'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/class/text': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
    'image/object/class/label': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
}

def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
  return tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)

parsed_image_dataset = raw_image_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)

for im in parsed_image_dataset:
    print(im['image/object/bbox/xmin'])
    print(im['image/object/bbox/xmax'])
    print(im['image/object/bbox/ymin'])
    print(im['image/object/bbox/ymax'])
    print(im['image/object/class/label'])
    break
```

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([0.390625  0.4687505], shape=(2,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([0.446875  0.5093755], shape=(2,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([0.3923828 0.4685552], shape=(2,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([0.4451172 0.5095708], shape=(2,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([1 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
```

- There are zero errors in stdout/err, so whatever's happening, it's silent.
- The images are (I assume) loading correctly, otherwise the whole thing would fail(?)
- I've clamped the boxes to be nonzero and <= 1
- Pretty sure I tried brute force setting the bounding boxes to e.g. [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] on every image, same problem.
- I tried debug logging, but it only prints the iteration/loss.

  1. Any ideas what I'm missing?
  2. Can I debug this somewhere? I'm not sure where in the API the labels get loaded.

Comment: I have read the function for creating `tf_example` and I could not find any problem within it either, but I do believe that the problem exists within tfrecrod files since you tried other tfrecords and it worked fine. Here is a link to where groundtruth boxes are extracted for visualisation. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f6f04066f893f15899ce077c2281541ff2fbb5eb/research/object_detection/model_lib.py#L443. In the same function, it will call vis_utils.VisualizeSingleFrameDetections that will then plot two subimages with detections on the left and groundtruth boxes on the right.

Comment: After a lot of fiddling (swapping images between my dataset and pets, swapping labels, etc), it turned out to be rogue newlines in my class text fields..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my class labels in each TFRecord had a newline at the end. This took more effort to discover than I'm willing to admit!

I had a .names file I was reading in, e.g.

```
cat
dog
horse
```

except it's not that, it's:

```
cat\n
dog\n
horse\n
```

and when I used `f.readlines()` to open my names file to get the classlabels, I was inadvertently storing the newlines in the record. Now, Tensorflow shouldn't actually use that text label. It has a label map file and uses the class ID in the model. I suspect what's happening is that whatever is being used to parse the TFRecord came across the newline in the `class/text` field and then ignored the label entirely.

Strongly suggest anyone doing this uses something like:

```
classes_text.append(names[class_id].rstrip().encode('utf8'))
```